# Regex .NET Multiline Capture

Tags: regex

I would like to capture the word "ABADDON", up to (not including ABAFT). I would then like to repeat this capture with "ABAFT", up to the next word (not including the next word). The words are capitalized.

```
ABADDON
A*bad"don, n. Etym: [Heb. abaddon destruction, abyss, fr. abad to be
lost, to perish.]

1. The destroyer, or angel of the bottomless pit; -- the same as
Apollyon and Asmodeus.

2. Hell; the bottomless pit. [Poetic]
In all her gates, Abaddon rues Thy bold attempt. Milton.

ABAFT
A*baft", prep. Etym: [Pref. a-on + OE. baft, baften, biaften, AS.
beæftan; be by + æftan behind. See After, Aft, By.] (Naut.)

Defn: Behind; toward the stern from; as, abaft the wheelhouse. Abaft
the beam. See under Beam.
```

Comment: So you want to capture everything between capitalized words?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand exactly what you mean, but here is a guess:

```
(?ms)^([A-Z]+)$(.+?)(?=^[A-Z]+$|\z)
```

The capital word would be in the first capturing group, and the text following it in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Taking off on @Qtax's answer, it could also be done like this:

`(?ms)^[A-Z]+$(?:(?!^[A-Z]+$).)*` or `/^[A-Z]+$(?:(?!^[A-Z]+$).)*/ms`

taking it further, to be forgiving to formatting while mantaining general form:

`(?ms)^[^\S\n]*[A-Z]+\s*$(?:(?!^[^\S\n]*[A-Z]+\s*$).)*`
or
`/^[^\S\n]*[A-Z]+\s*$(?:(?!^[^\S\n]*[A-Z]+\s*$).)*/ms`